# Propagate errors from logarithmic scale to linear model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

So I have the given exponential model:
$y = \beta_0 * x ^{\beta_1}$

In order to estimate $\beta_i$ I take the $\log_{10}$ of the system to work with linear model and use linear regression: $\log_{10}y = \log_{10}\beta_0 + \beta_1 \log_{10}x$. After fitting I get the associated standard deviation error $\delta\log_{10}\beta_0$ and $\delta\beta_1$.

How can I propagate the errors back to the exponential form so that I can write the result as:
$y = (\beta_0\pm\delta\beta_0) * x ^{(\beta_1\pm\delta\beta_1)}$

Would it simply be propagating the error of $\beta_0$ as $\delta\beta_0 = \frac{\partial \log_{10}\beta_0}{\partial \beta_0}*\delta\log_{10}\beta_0$ and leave $\delta\beta_1$ as it is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this: https://web.stanford.edu/~kimth/www-mit/8.13/error_propagation.pdf

Comment: It would have been slightly less messy if you'd worked with natural logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **transformation law of random variables** to calculate how the uncertainty in X transforms into the uncertainty of Y
$$=() ⇒  = \left|\frac{∂}{∂}\right|\cdot $$
However, be aware that this method  yields different optimal fit-parameters (and uncertainty) compared to a non-linear fit. This is due to the fact that  least-square fits put more weight onto "larger" deviations compared to  "small" deviations. There exists a vast literature on how to optimise least-square fits by using different penalty function.